# How to force pdf's to open in Adobe when using IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, adobe, windows-server-2008

We are having an issue where we have links to a PDF on our site which are usually long guides.

These guides have links all over them.  We have all of the links to open in a new window but IE is not playing well with that at all.  Every other browser works fine but in IE the links open in the same window and user loses the guide - which they will need in a few minutes.

I know there are user settings to combat this and I know they can hold down control while going to link but our users (and thousands of them) are too techie.  So was hoping to do something on server side to make sure that the PDFs are forced to open in Acrobat when using IE or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Apache you could force the users to download the files by placing this in a .htaccess file.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

I imagine similar options will exist for whatever server you are using.

[Source with other options](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/forum/topic/force-a-file-to-download-instead-of-showing-up-in-the-browser)

Comment: It is Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: [How to do the same thing using IIS](http://forums.iis.net/t/1190624.aspx?IIS+Force+download+of+PDF)

Comment: Let me see if that plays well with my other rewrite rules.